# ML.NET - ForecastBySsa

Tags: ml.net

I'm evaluating and testing ForecastBySsa and I'm not really impressed with the result.

1) Example from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.forecastbyssa?view=ml-dotnet

The example show a time series of 5 data points, repeated 3 times with values 0,1,2,3,4.

The forecasted next five values are:
// Forecasted values: // [1.977226, 1.020494, 1.760543, 3.437509, 4.266461]

Hmm... Why 1.97? Far from zero. And overall - not that good?

2) Testing with airline passenger data dataset

Testing the algorithm with data from:
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/311446_08b00d63cc794e158b1f4763eb70d43a.html

And get the following forecast

[Click here to see forecast!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkM8r.png)

Questions:

a) Anyone having good forecasting results using ML.NET ForecastBySsa?

b) Anyone having a good example with some real dataset and parameters etc?

/Erik

Comment: In order to identify the issue with Airline forecast , it would be helpful if you share your code. Otherwise it is not possible to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the parameter windowSize to 13, not 12. Because 13 is a complete cycle.

Answer (score 0):

the example is incomprehensible as the meaning of the input parameters are not explained. The predicted data are bad, it is not absolutely clear how to improve them. In the example there is this piece of code, but what does it mean? The results do not improve anyway. Seen thus always unusable.

```
// Update with new observations.
        forecastEngine.Predict(new TimeSeriesData(0));
        forecastEngine.Predict(new TimeSeriesData(0));
        forecastEngine.Predict(new TimeSeriesData(0));
        forecastEngine.Predict(new TimeSeriesData(0));
```

the only article with more information is this, hopefully it will help

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/main/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Forecasting-Sales/README.md